# Android Studio 3.0 -> Servlet Module

Tags: android-studio-3.0

How to set up the Servlet Module in Android Studio 3.0?

I already tried to create a new module on a new project, but the view has changed from the version of Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Add new module for android studio 3.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run / Debug Configurations.**

Click on **+** Button, add App Engine DevAppServer.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**: Import the module of Android Studio 2.3.3